# How to change value for checkcolumn in grid

Tags: extjs, grid

I got grid with columns:

...

```
    columns: [
        {
        xtype: 'rownumberer'
    }, {
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        sortable: false,
        header: 'done',
        dataIndex: 'status',
        flex: 2,
        width: 55,
        callback: function(success, model) {
            this.setRawValue(success); // DOESNT WORK
this.setValue(success); // DOESNT WORK
        },
}
...
```

I would like to change checkbox state to checked or unchecked. Functions setValue() or setRawValue() have no effect for the checkbox - moreover - there are not available for
the widget.

Is there simple function like setChecked(boolean) in extjs for checkcolumn?

It is ridiculous I have instance 'checkcolumn' but I can't find basic function.

I will be glad for any hint. Thank you.

Bogus

Comment: You're looking at this problem from the completely wrong direction.  Add the manipulation should happen on the model of the row displayed, not the checkbox. See the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

for record in grid store with 'fieldName' checkcolumn write

```
record.set('fieldName',false)
```

or

```
record.set('fieldName',true)
```

it make field selected/deselected

Answer (score 2):

the most simple way is to do it in the store , you can add a new boolean field in the store with default of true to do that , and later just change that boolean in the store and the grid will be reflected with the changes